# Getting Port: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. and nothing has worked. Literally

Tags: google-chrome-extension

So, I've looked into every other Stack Overflow post on this topic, changed everything I could line by line, and nothing is working. (Nevermind that 99% of this code is straight off dev.google.com) No matter what I try, I get the error mentioned in the title. There doesn't seem to be an explanation, so I'm hoping this group can spot the potentially stupid thing I'm missing. Thanks!

Manifest.json

```
  {
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Topic Fetch",
  "description": "This extension extracts the meta keywords from a news article and give you related articles from Google News",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title" : "Get Related Links"
  },

    "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["Content-Script.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],

  "permissions": [
    "tabs","<all_urls>",
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
console.log(tabs);
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, "message", function(response) {
    alert(response);
});
});
```

Content-Script.js

```
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
      sendResponse('Hello!');
  });
```

EDIT: Here's the code I'm using (for the most part) and info about message passing in Chrome extensions: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I've added the article I'm working from, and you'll see the code is set up verbatim, so I'm wondering what sort of listener I'd need to add? I'm kind of a n00b; please forgive me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content script code won't run until you refresh the page, so it isn't listening yet. The code in the background.js is not intended to be run immediately (as you have it). It should only be run after you have confirmed that the tab is listening.

I suggest trying the opposite way first: listen with the background.js and send a message with the content script.